# Angular 2 unit test http.get undefined

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I am trying to write the angular 2 unit test for async http service using MockBackend but getting http.get undefined error. Here is my code:

Http Service:

```ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http,Headers,RequestOptions,Response } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class HttpService {


    constructor(private _http: Http) {}

    /**
     *  Http request will time out if not received response within 20 sec
     * 
     * @param url
     * @returns {Observable<R>}
     */
    getData(url : string) {
        return this._http.get(url)
            .timeout(20000, new Error('delay exceeded'))
            .map(response => response.json());
    }

}
```

My Custom component method for which I am writing unit test:

```ts
 private loadDetails(input : string){
        this._httpService.getData("/api/test"+ input)
            .subscribe(
                data => {this.user = data,
                         // Some more logic in here based on data     
                },
                error =>  { console.log( error);}
            );
    }
```

Unit Test :

```ts
import { HttpService } from "../shared/services/http.service";
import {
    async,
    inject,
    fakeAsync,
    TestBed
} from '@angular/core/testing';

import {
Http,
    BaseRequestOptions,
    Response,
    BaseResponseOptions,
    ResponseOptions
} from '@angular/http';

import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import {
    MockBackend,
    MockConnection
} from '@angular/http/testing';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';

import { TestingComponent } from './testing.component';

const mockHttpProvider = {
    deps: [ MockBackend, BaseRequestOptions ],
    useFactory: (backend: MockBackend, defaultOptions: BaseRequestOptions) => {
        return new Http(backend, defaultOptions);
    }
}

describe('testingComponent', () => {

    let fixture,testingComponent;

    // provide our implementations or mocks to the dependency injector
    beforeEach(() => {

        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [
                CustomComponent
            ],
            providers: [
                HttpService,
                MockBackend,
                BaseRequestOptions,
                {provide: Http, useValue: mockHttpProvider}
            ]
        });

        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(PortfolioComponent);
        testingComponent = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    });


    it('should call loadDetails to load user details',  inject(
        [IPIQHttpService, MockBackend],
        fakeAsync((service: HttpService, backend: MockBackend) => {
            backend.connections.subscribe((connection: MockConnection) => {

                let mockResponseBody= {
                    id: '123',
                    title: 'test',
                    empno: '456'
                };

                let response = new ResponseOptions({body: JSON.stringify(mockResponseBody)});
                connection.mockRespond(new Response(response));
            });
            testingComponent.loadUserDetails('123');
            expect(testingComponent.user.empno).toEqual('456');
        })));


});
```

when I am calling   testingComponent.loadUserDetails('123') to call the http service , I am getting http.get method undefined.

Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally it's working. Here are the changes I have made:

1. Imported HttpModule and changed the way I was using mockHttpProvider as suggested by @ Günter Zöchbauer in previous post:

```
const mockHttpProvider =  
{ 
provide: Http,
 deps: [ MockBackend, BaseRequestOptions ], 
useFactory: (backend: MockBackend, defaultOptions: BaseRequestOptions) => 
{ return new Http(backend, defaultOptions); } 
}

 TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [HttpModule], // <<<=== added
        declarations: [
            CustomComponent
        ],
        providers: [
            HttpService,
            MockBackend,
            BaseRequestOptions,
            mockHttpProvider
        ]
    });
```

3. Changed my unit test and removed fakeAsync:

```
it('should call loadDetails to load user details', inject([HttpService, MockBackend, Http], (_httpService, backend, http) => {
        backend.connections.subscribe(connection => {
            let mockResponseBody= {
                 id: '123',
                 title: 'test',
                 empno: '456'
            };
            let response = new ResponseOptions({body: JSON.stringify(mockResponseBody)});
            connection.mockRespond(new Response(response));
        });
        testingComponent.loadDetails('123');
        expect(testingComponent.user.empno).toEqual('456');
    }));
```

Answer (score 4):

```
const mockHttpProvider = { 
    provide: Http,
    deps: [ MockBackend, BaseRequestOptions ],
    useFactory: (backend: MockBackend, defaultOptions: BaseRequestOptions) => {
        return new Http(backend, defaultOptions);
    }
}
```

```ts
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [HttpModule], // <<<=== added
        declarations: [
            CustomComponent
        ],
        providers: [
            HttpService,
            MockBackend,
            BaseRequestOptions,
            mockHttpProvider
        ]
    });
```

Comment: I have added HttpModule import but still getting the same error:  TypeError: this._http.get is not a function

Comment: Can you please create a new question where you add your test code?

Comment: Sorry, Not sure what you mean by your test code?. I have already posted my test code in here.

Comment: Don't know. I was sure it wasn't there yesterday. Perhaps my vision was impaired ;-). Have you tried to add `console.log(_http)` to `HttpService`. Usually when injection fails it throws but in your case the app seems to continue which is weird.

Comment: What is `IPIQHttpService` and where is `loadDetails` being called from?

Comment: Sorry. IPIQHttpService should be HttpService. It's just I missed changing the name when I was pasted in here. loadDetails is being called from unit test where it says testingComponent.loadUserDetails('123'); . Typo again when putting on stack overflow, it should testingComponent.loadDetails ('123').

Comment: Also, result from

Comment: console.log(_http) result: Object{deps: [function MockBackend() { ... }, function BaseRequestOptions() { ... }], useFactory: function (backend, defaultOptions) { ... }}

Comment: if you notice I am using mockHttpProvide: const mockHttpProvider = {
    deps: [ MockBackend, BaseRequestOptions ],
    useFactory: (backend: MockBackend, defaultOptions: BaseRequestOptions) => {
        return new Http(backend, defaultOptions);
    }
}. Is that correct?

Comment: Good hint. Didn't see that but it looks wrong. I updated my answer.

Comment: I made these chages :  {provide: Http, useValue: mockHttpProvider} and const mockHttpProvider =  { provide: Http, deps: [ MockBackend, BaseRequestOptions ], useFactory: (backend: MockBackend, defaultOptions: BaseRequestOptions) => { return new Http(backend, defaultOptions); } }. Same error still: TypeError: this._http.get is not a function

Comment: Sorry. I take it back. http.get error is gone and now I am getting: Error: 4 periodic timer(s) still in the queue.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I actually got it working. Posting my changes as answer.